# Getting Apache cgi to send json in Python

Tags: python, ajax, apache, cgi

I have an apache server that I am using for cgi.  I am writing my cgis in Python.

As long as my responses are of the form "Content-Type: text/html\n #" it works.

But if I send anything else, I get a 500 error and my logs say "malformed header from script. Bad header"  Can I change my configurations to make it work?  Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with all CGI, you need a blank line between the headers and the body.

```
print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
print
print 'Hello, World!'
```

Comment: Wow!  That was it.  I can't believe that was all it was.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send a Content-Type header to tell the browser what type of data you're sending it. Without that you'll get the 500 error you're experiencing.

Comment: This is true.  I tried sending a Content-Type, but it didn't work due to the fact that I didn't add a space line.